# Can't Open ASP.Net Beta 4 Solution after Upgrading to ASP.Net RC1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a solution that was built using ASP.Net Beta 4.  After upgrading to ASP.Net RC1, I am unable to open the solution in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

In the Solution Explorer, it says

> < ProjectName > (Incompatible)

When I expand it, it says

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio

When I opened the project, it created a "Migration Report" and the migration report says

> src\< ProjectName >\< ProjectName >.xproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=628321&projecttype=8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B

The link provided talks about using Visual Studio 2013 to open projects that were created in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, which is completely not helpful.

Any ideas? What do I need to do in order to open this Solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You should update the project to every text beta version if you started to use some beta. Typical strategy is providing updates (automatic migration) *only from one of two previous beta version*. You skipped beta4-beta8 and try to use rc1 with probably update1 for Visual Studio 2015. It should not work. Many internal structures was changes multiple times. For example, the configuration file `hosting.ini` was renamed to `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini` and then to `hosting.json`. The same history have many internal structures and the names of IIS and assemblies.

Comment: I know that changes will need to be made in order to get it to build, but do these changes prevent Visual Studio from even opening the project? I can't even get the project loaded. I assumed it would be able to open but not build it.

Comment: try to delete your VS project file (`.kproj`, `.xproj`)  and open it from your `project.json`, VS should recreate a `.xproj`it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Visual Studio Code to follow Shawn Wildermuth's posts on upgrading from one version to another.

http://wildermuth.com/2015/7/22/Upgrading_ASP_NET_5_Beta4_to_Beta5
http://wildermuth.com/2015/10/20/Upgrading_from_ASP_NET_5_Beta_7_to_Beta_8
http://wildermuth.com/2015/11/18/Upgrading_ASP_NET_5_Beta_8_to_RC1

After that it build build use command line tools but I still couldn't open it in Visual Studio 2015.

When I initially installed ASP.Net RC1 I used the instructions to install it via command line.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html

I reinstalled it but this time I used the "Install ASP.NET 5 with Visual Studio" instructions.

After doing that everything worked correctly. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Thanks!